# How do I insert an html layout file into a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

So right now I have a popup div (this is for a chrome extension) and right now the div pops up just fine.

What I would like to do is to inject this layout file that I created (lots of itty bitty design parts) into the div.  How would I go about doing this. I tried to set the innerHTML property to index.html (the layout file)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // Mouse listener for any move event on the current document.

  console.log("started"); //debug for starting
  var popupStatus = 0; // set value

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var srcElement = e.srcElement;
    // Lets check if our underlying element is a DIV.
    if (srcElement.nodeName == 'A' || srcElement.nodeName == 'STRONG') {  
      loadPopup();  
    }
    else{
      disablePopup();
    }
  }, true);

  function loadPopup() { 
    var x = document.getElementById("index");
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
      $('<div/>', {
        id: 'cover',
        innerHTML: index.html //line in question (making it "index.html" doesn't work)
      }).appendTo(document.documentElement);
      $('#cover').fadeTo("slow",1);
      popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }   
  }

  function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
      $('#cover').fadeTo("slow",0);
      $('#cover').remove();
      popupStatus = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use ajax to get the content of the file 'index.html'.

A snippet like this:

```
$.get("index.html", function( data ) {
    $.('body').append('<div id="cover">' + data + '</div>');
});
```

could be placed at the line in question. Replace 'body' with whatever suits to your needs. The snippet can be certainly improved, but for now it should give you an idea.

I'm not aware of other possibilities to read files with JavaScript on the client side.

Or now I see, better make it:

```
$.get("index.html", function( data ) {
    $('<div/>', {
        id: 'cover',
        innerHTML: data
    }).appendTo(document.documentElement);
});
```

within the if-condition.

I'm not completely sure what you want to make, but it seems that you want to append it to the element with ID 'index'. Than you should change that appropriately in the last line.

EDIT:

Here are some slight changes:

```
$.get("index.html", function( data ) {
    $('<div/>', {
        id: 'cover',
        html: data // this was making the problem
    }).appendTo(x); // append to the element saved in the variable x
}, "html"); // state explicitly that the payload of data is HTML
```

that make the snippet working for me.

Comment: To correct your answer for Chrome Extensions: the address should not be `"index.html"` but `chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html")` to ensure the right path regardless of the origin.

Comment: Thanks @Xan. The answer was just thought as a solution guide, giving an idea how to solve the problem, and not as a complete solution. I didn't know this issue with the Chrome Extensions, so I learned something new.

Comment: Hmm tried this but now the div isn't showing up at all

Comment: I tried the code and it needs slight changes. Please take a look above in the edited part.